# Which numerical method to use for integrating functions with complex_ode?

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers

I am trying to integrate differential equations in Python that have the following form:

```
def rhs_FD(r, u, l, omega, bkg_func):

    # u = H1, K

    H1_r = u[0]
    K_r = u[1]

    lamb_r = bkg_func(r)[0]
    nu_r = bkg_func(r)[1]
    p_r = bkg_func(r)[2]
    rho_r = bkg_func(r)[3]
    gamma_r = bkg_func(r)[4]

    #Lambda, nu, p, rho e gamma are interpolated functions

    pi = math.pi

    aux0 = (4. * ((r ** 2) * (omega ** 2))) + (-8. * ((np.exp(((lamb_r) + (nu_r)))) * (l * ((1. + l) * (pi * ((r ** 2) * (p_r)))))))

    H1l = (((np.exp((lamb_r))) * ((K_r) + (aux0))) - (l * (H1_r))) / r
    KL = (0.5 * (((l * ((1. + l) * (H1_r))) + aux0) - ((3. + (2. * l)) * (K_r)))) / r
    
    rhs_FD = [0]*2

    rhs_FD[0] = H1l
    rhs_FD[1] = Kl

    return np.array(rhs_FD)
```

`Omega` can take complex values, and the integration is performed with respect to the variable `r`. I have assembled a function for integration using `scipy.integrate.complex_ode`:

```
def integrate_origin(k0, w0, bkg_func, l, omega, file_eos):   
  
    nu0 = bkg_func(0.00001)[1]
    p0 = bkg_func(0.00001)[2]
    rho0 = bkg_func(0.00001)[3]
    gamma0 = bkg_func(0.00001)[4]   
    
    solver = ode(rhs_FD)
    solver.set_integrator('dop853')
    
    r0 = 0.0001
    u0 = [6.66666739e-01 -4.36685255e-09j, 9.99999964e-01 -6.49601793e-09j]
    
    solver.set_initial_value(u0, r0)
    
    solver.set_f_params(l, omega, bkg_func)
    
    r = np.linspace(0.0001, 0.08, 160)
    
    u_list = []
    
    for r in r_list:
        u = solver.integrate(r)
        u_list.append(u)
        
    sol_in = np.array(u_list).tolist()
    
    return sol_in
```

where

```
k0 = 1
w0 = 0
l = 2
omega = 1+1j
bkg_func = # Functions of the integration variable r
```

When using `scipy.integrate.ode` and real values of `omega`, the above structure worked well. But when using `scipy.integrate.complex_ode`, the error `TypeError: can't convert complex to float` arises. Could the problem be in the numerical method I am using to integrate the functions (`'dop853'`)? What other method can I change to or what modification can I make in the integrate function to make the code work for the complex domain?

Comment: (1) Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Simplify the problem and share enough code for us to run. (2) How is this question different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76767443/12131013)?

Comment: For the record, OP deleted their previous question after I brought attention to it in my previous comment. Those with >10k reputation will be able to see that deleted question.